in Flutter, CachedNetworkImage doesn't work (doesn't load from CachedData)
Chrome DevTools network Tab
example video
As you can see in the example video, when a category is selected from the space on the left, the corresponding items are displayed on the screen. The main issue is the delay that occurs when switching categories, even though the images have already been loaded and cached.
I believe this delay is caused by the time it takes to retrieve the cached images from memory. I have tried numerous methods to preload the widgets, but all attempts have failed.
While experimenting, I happened to look at the network tab in Chrome DevTools and noticed that the images were coming in through network requests, not from the cache. It appears that CachedNetworkImage is not functioning properly.
Here is my code about cachedNetworkImage.
Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
         color: Colors.black, width: 2.0),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
    child: ClipRRect(
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
         child: CachedNetworkImage(
             key: ValueKey(tileData['imageCode']),
             cacheKey: tileData['imageCode'],
             imageUrl: widget.menuData['imageCode']
                              [tileData['imageCode']],
             cacheManager: CustomCacheManager.instance,
             fit: BoxFit.cover)))

class CustomCacheManager {
  static const key = 'imageCache';

  static CacheManager instance = CacheManager(
    Config(
      key,
      stalePeriod: const Duration(days: 1),
      maxNrOfCacheObjects: 100, // 최대 캐시 객체 수를 100개로 제한
      repo: JsonCacheInfoRepository(databaseName: key),
      fileService: HttpFileService(),
    ),
  );
}

there is full code
  void _menuPreRender() {
    _menuWidgets.clear();

    for (Map<String, dynamic> category in _menuData['toManageList']) {
      _menuWidgets[category['name']] = MenuView(
          key: ValueKey(category['name']),
          menuData: _menuData,
          category: category['name'],
          updateCallback: (int selectedMenuIndex) {
            return () {
              setState(() {
                _selectedMenu = selectedMenuIndex;
                _mainAreaWidget = _menuEdit(isEdit: true);
              });
            };
          },
          setManageMenuData: (Map<String, dynamic> data) {
            _setManageMenuData(data);
          });
    }
  }

/* ... */

class MenuView extends StatefulWidget {
  const MenuView(
      {super.key,
      required this.menuData,
      required this.category,
      required this.updateCallback,
      required this.setManageMenuData});

  final String category;
  final Map<String, dynamic> menuData;
  final Function(int selectedMenuIndex) updateCallback;
  final Function(Map<String, dynamic>) setManageMenuData;

  @override
  State<MenuView> createState() => _MenuViewState();
}

class _MenuViewState extends State<MenuView>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    for (var menu in widget.menuData['toManage'][widget.category]['menu']) {
      if (menu['imageCode'] != null && menu['imageCode'] != '') {
        precacheImage(
            NetworkImage(widget.menuData['imageCode'][menu['imageCode']]),
            context);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    print('category: ${widget.category}');
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return ReorderableListView.builder(
      buildDefaultDragHandles: false,
      itemCount: widget.menuData['toManage'][widget.category]['menu'].length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        Map<String, dynamic> tileData =
            widget.menuData['toManage'][widget.category]['menu'][index];

        return ListTile(
            key: Key('$index'),
            title: SizedBox(
              height: screenHeight * 0.15,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        tileData['name'],
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 5),
                      Text(
                        tileData['description'],
                        style:
                            const TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.grey),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 5),
                      Text(
                        '${tileData['price']}원',
                        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                      width: screenHeight * 0.14,
                      height: screenHeight * 0.14,
                      child: tileData['imageCode'] != null
                          ? Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border.all(
                                      color: Colors.black, width: 2.0),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                              child: ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                  child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                      key: ValueKey(tileData['imageCode']),
                                      cacheKey: tileData['imageCode'],
                                      imageUrl: widget.menuData['imageCode']
                                          [tileData['imageCode']],
                                      cacheManager: CustomCacheManager.instance,
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover)))
                          : const SizedBox.shrink()),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            onTap: widget.updateCallback(index),
            trailing: Container(
              width: screenHeight * 0.08,
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, // Container 내부의 아이콘을 중앙에 배치
              child: ReorderableDragStartListener(
                  index: index,
                  child: Icon(Icons.drag_handle_rounded,
                      size: screenHeight * 0.08)),
            ));
      },
      onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
        List<Map<String, dynamic>> menuList =
            widget.menuData['toManage'][widget.category]['menu'];

        setState(() {
          if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
            newIndex -= 1;
          }

          final Map<String, dynamic> item = menuList.removeAt(oldIndex);
          menuList.insert(newIndex, item);
        });

        widget.setManageMenuData(widget.menuData['toManage']);
      },
    );
  }
}


What I want is for the images that have already been loaded to be displayed to the users instantly without any delay when switching categories. I believe there must be a way to achieve this since many commercial apps support similar functionality.

If you want to precache image NetworkImage will not work use CachedNetworkImageProvider

It appears you are developing the app for flutter web.
The documentation for cached_network_image says the following:

Both the CachedNetworkImage as CachedNetworkImageProvider have minimal support for web. It currently doesn't include caching.

That said, you can always create your own widget to solve this problem.
Here is a simple implementation of a widget that caches network images by making an http get request, and storing the url and resulting bytes in a hashmap. If you look up the same url again, it will simply pull the bytes from the hashmap rather than make another get request. This is a bit of an oversimplified solution since it does not ever remove images from the cache, which could be considered a memory leak.
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


class CustomCacheImage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomCacheImage(this.src, {this.height, this.width, super.key});

  final String src;
  final double? height;
  final double? width;

  @override
  State<CustomCacheImage> createState() => _CustomCacheImageState();
}

class _CustomCacheImageState extends State<CustomCacheImage> {
  static final Map<String, Uint8List> _cache = {};

  Uint8List? _cached;
  Future<Uint8List>? _future;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _cached = _cache[widget.src]; // attempt to retrieve image from cache
    if (_cached == null) {
      // if image not in cache, fetch from network
      _future = http.get(Uri.parse(widget.src)).then((response) {
        Uint8List bytes = response.bodyBytes;
        _cache[widget.src] = bytes; // store image in cache
        return bytes;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _future,
      initialData: _cached,
      builder: (context, snapshot) => switch (snapshot) {
        // handle future error state
        AsyncSnapshot(hasError: true) => const Placeholder(),
        // handle future loading state
        AsyncSnapshot(hasData: false) => const Placeholder(),
        // handle future completed successfully
        AsyncSnapshot(hasData: true, :var data) => Image.memory(
            data!,
            width: widget.width,
            height: widget.height,
            // handle image invalid
            errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) => const Placeholder(),
          ),
      },
    );
  }
}

Below is a complete example app that makes use of the above widget:
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

const animals = [
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Llamas%2C_Vernagt-Stausee%2C_Italy.jpg',
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9e/Giraffe_Mikumi_National_Park.jpg',
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/African_Bush_Elephant.jpg',
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/07/Didelphis_virginiana_with_young.JPG',
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3e/Raccoon_in_Central_Park_%2835264%29.jpg',
];

const objects = [
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/AT%26T_push_button_telephone_western_electric_model_2500_dmg_black.jpg',
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Plastic_Tuinstoel.jpg',
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/06/ElectricBlender.jpg',
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ea/Magnifying_glass_with_focus_on_paper.png',
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/Roller-skate.jpg',
  // these last 2 are intentionally errors
  'ewfwefewwfssd',
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/nreijfoisejfisejfoif.jpg',
];

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: HomePage(),
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      initialIndex: 0,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Cache Demo'),
          bottom: const TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: 'Animals'),
              Tab(text: 'Objects'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(children: [
          ListView(children: [
            for (var link in animals)
              CustomCacheImage(link, height: 200, width: 200),
          ]),
          ListView(children: [
            for (var link in objects)
              CustomCacheImage(link, height: 200, width: 200),
          ]),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomCacheImage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomCacheImage(this.src, {this.height, this.width, super.key});

  final String src;
  final double? height;
  final double? width;

  @override
  State<CustomCacheImage> createState() => _CustomCacheImageState();
}

class _CustomCacheImageState extends State<CustomCacheImage> {
  static final Map<String, Uint8List> _cache = {};

  Uint8List? _cached;
  Future<Uint8List>? _future;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _cached = _cache[widget.src]; // attempt to retrieve image from cache
    if (_cached == null) {
      // if image not in cache, fetch from network
      _future = http.get(Uri.parse(widget.src)).then((response) {
        Uint8List bytes = response.bodyBytes;
        _cache[widget.src] = bytes; // store image in cache
        return bytes;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _future,
      initialData: _cached,
      builder: (context, snapshot) => switch (snapshot) {
        // handle future error state
        AsyncSnapshot(hasError: true) => const Placeholder(),
        // handle future loading state
        AsyncSnapshot(hasData: false) => const Placeholder(),
        // handle future completed successfully
        AsyncSnapshot(hasData: true, :var data) => Image.memory(
            data!,
            width: widget.width,
            height: widget.height,
            // handle image invalid
            errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) => const Placeholder(),
          ),
      },
    );
  }
}

